# HttpConfiguration MapHttpRoute different controller for request with and without QueryString

Tags: controller, querystringparameter

I am trying to support two HTTP requests as below:

- http://localhost:80/bookstore/book/1 <== this gets the actual book (ID = 1) in binary
- http://localhost:80/bookstore/book/1/?include=title&include=author <== this returns the title and author of book (ID = 1) in Json

I have something like this but only the bookMeta controller gets hit:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "bookMeta",
            routeTemplate: "/book/{bookID}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "bookMeta",                    
                bookID= RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "bookBinary",
            routeTemplate: "/book/{bookID}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "bookBinary",                    
                bookID= RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Obviously they are duplicate routes which doesn't work.

So my question is, how can I set up the `MapHttpRoute` to tell the above two requests to goto two different controllers (`bookBinary` and `bookMetadata`)?